# Returning and parsing json array via php and jquery post

Tags: php, json, jquery-post

I'm trying to return a json array of names pulled from my database. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but it never gets to the alert call. The returned data doesn't have to be json, I was just trying that approach first. It completes the INSERT call and I know that it is returning the correct data set. What's wrong with my code?

Javascript

```
function showDB() {
    $.post('example.php', $('#infoForm').serialize(), function(data) {  
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
            alert(item);
        });
    }, "json");
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $host = "www.host.com";
    $user = "user";
    $pwd = "password";
    $db = "exampleDB";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd)or die("Error connecting to database.");
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $db) or die("Couldn't select the database."); 

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];   
    $nameArray = array();

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $query = "INSERT INTO people VALUES (?, ?)";
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query) or die("Failed to prepare statement.");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $name, $color);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    $query = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS dupes FROM people GROUP BY name ORDER BY dupes DESC LIMIT 20";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while ($row = $mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($nameArray, $row['name']);
    }

    echo json_encode($nameArray);

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Instead of using `alert`, how about using `console.log` to see if there are error? Let us know the output.

Comment: POST http://www.website.com/test/example.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
and the response is 0

Comment: Are you able to execute the php-code by itself?

Comment: Console.log()  on variable json in js-code. What does it return?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it echos "0" so it must be a problem with how I'm creating the array or the query. When I run the same query in mysqladmin, it returns the correct result set. Is there something that would cause me to get a different/incorrect result set when calling it from my php file?

Comment: Do a print_r($nameArray) - give us the output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your PHP code.

Find this line of code:

```
$nameArray[] = "";
```

Replace to this line of code:

```
$nameArray = array();
```

---

### Update

Find this line of code:

```
$query = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS dupes FROM people GROUP BY name ORDER BY dupes DESC LIMIT 20;";
```

Replace to this line of code

```
$query = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS dupes FROM people GROUP BY name ORDER BY dupes DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Note the semicolon inside the string.

---

### Update Once Again

Find this line of code:

```
while ($row = $mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Replace to this line of code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

`mysqli_fetch_array` is a function.

Comment: nahh, you can do that in PHP, you'll just get `$nameArray=array(0=>"")`, but it's not what's causing the 500.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? The function `json_encode` works only PHP 5.2 and better.

Comment: There it is. It's always something small like that with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have error here

```
$nameArray[] = "";
```

and you need to replace this with

```
$nameArray[] = array();
```

Now the reason is this that in your code you are initializing an array with no values and not even any index so this will generate error. but if you replace it with `array()` it will initialize an array.
When you will push values `array_push($nameArray, $row['name']);` into this it will push value in array on index 0 and then on 1 and so on.